# Json with android

Tags: java, android, json

we are developing app designing process in one computer.we not using SQLlite for connectivity instead of using servlet in another computer data fetches from one cmputer and send through another computer.at the run time if the person enter empid means corresponds id data want to fetch from another computer.now the problem is json output is clear but it not displaying to android design computer.if he enter id showing ADMIN null in my console i dnt knw which side problem frndz .showing null error.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
    JSONArray jary = new JSONArray();
    try 
    {
      String empid;
      empid = request.getParameter("empid");
      System.out.println(empid);
      jary = PermissionLeave.plManagement(empid);
      JsonParser.sendResponseArray("Permission",jary, response);
```

**OUTPUT:**

> {"Permission":[{"empid":"ADMIN","PorL":"PERMISSION","name":"ADMINISTRATOR","date":"2015-07-23","rowid":106},{"empid":"ADMIN","PorL":"PERMISSION","name":"ADMINISTRATOR","date":"2015-07-23","rowid":107},]}

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use GSON for conversion from JSON to Object and Object to JSON.

[Link 1](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)
[Link 2](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/)

What client are you using in your Android app to connect to the Servlet? Apache's HttpClient?  You can use any client to connect to the Server. I recommend Apache HTTP Client. On the Server Side you just have to do

```
   String jsonData =request.gerParameter("myBean");
    //And then
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    gson.fromJson(jsonData,MyBean.class);
```

Reference link for Apache Client is [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/)

**EDIT:**

I am not clear as to what you are exactly trying to do. This is what I have understood.

- Your Android App passes one empid eg. "ADMIN". You receive that on server side in Servlet. Then using emp_id you fetch details of that user using  `PermissionLeave.plManagement` in Json Array Format. Then you send response back to Android using 
  `JsonParser.sendResponseArray("Permission",jary, response);` in JSON Array Format,
  (Please note JSON Array and JSON Object is different, they are parsed in different ways)

  Is my understanding correct?

Now on the Android side you are receiving response in JSON format, I think you are not parsing this JSON array back to Object, that is why you are facing a problem. Where are you receiving a null ? On Server side or Android side?

Comment: thanks oliver i used json only problem is when i am receiving empid from from the android i m receiving ADMIN null from that guy.my side servlet is correct i m thinking bcz i m receiving  json object as output..but he receiving no values for empid showing in  LOGCAT.tat problem help me

Comment: ya exactly correct oliver null receiving in server side.  ADMIN
                                                                                               null like this receiving in server side

Comment: @pritha In this case, there are two possibilities 1) You are not sending data correctly from Android to Servlet. OR 2)You are sending correct data but you are receiving it in wrong manner on Server side. Please show me the code on the Android side (The code where you send the info from Android to Servlet).

Comment: android to servlet code    public class Permission extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
         
      
      

      
      protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
       List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
       
          params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("empid",userName));
         
          json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_applyPermission, "GET", params1);
          
          return null;
      }
      
     }

Comment: android to server code: public class Permission extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
         
      
      

      
      protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
       List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
       
          params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("empid",userName));
         
          json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_applyPermission, "GET", params1);
          
          return null;
      }
      
     }

Comment: I see nothing wrong in your code as of now. Let me check thoroughly once again. Please wait for some time.

Comment: thankz oliver.only this manual getting problem before login.leave types same procedure but in this at current time it want ti fetch data for the empid.but in streamwriter no prblm i m facing.